# How do I disable the "lp" kernel module permanently

Tags: linux, kernel

How do I disable autoload of the `lp` kernel module?

What I've tried so far:

- Try to disabel the module via blacklist

  ```
  echo "blacklist lp">>/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist
  echo "blacklist lp">>/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
  ```
- Recreated the linux image

  ```
  sudo dpkg-reconfigure linux-image-$(uname -r)
  ```

Even after reboot, the module was loaded again.

Brute force `rm /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/char/lp.ko` is working fine, but looks ugly to me ;)

Answer (score 2):

your brute force solution is fine in my books :)
try lsmod when the module is loaded and see if there is anything in the used by column,
there is a chance another module loads it as a dependency

Comment: No there's nothing in the "Used By" list.
Honestly, I can not remember why I've asked that question.